# Не работает команда taskkill

Tags: cmd, bat

Изучаю командную строку. Открываю cmd и пишу 'taskkill /f /im /calc.exe', калькулятор закрылся. Потом хочу перенести этот код в bat файл и через этот файл закрыть калькулятор, но именно через bat файл этот код не срабатывает. Почему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Одной из полезных команд бат-файлов является `%errorlevel%`, которая возвращает код последней ошибки. По этому коду вы сможете определить, на каком именно этапе у вас возникает ошибка.

```
taskkill /f /im /calc.exe
exit /b %errorlevel%
```